# How do I use CSS to select for a tag with arbitrary name attribute?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This will allow me to select for the "a" tag with name of educationalTraining:

```
a[name=educationalTraining] {
    color: rgb(89, 91, 91);
}
```

How would I get all "a" tags with any name. This doesn't seem to work:

```
a[name=*] {
    color: rgb(89, 91, 91);
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't just select for any "a" tags. It's only ones that use the name attribute that I am interested in.

Comment: a[name] { ... css ... }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
a[name] {
    color: rgb(89, 91, 91);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gQL9J/

Comment: See (among other places) the CSS2 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) and this MDN page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
a[name] {
    color: rgb(89, 91, 91);
}
```